# access violation stack overflow c++

Tags: c++, stack, overflow

every one...

I am very new in C++...
My problem is about reading a big text file in C++ visual studio 2012...

Here is my simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double x;
    int i,j;
    ifstream inFile;
    i=0;
    j=0;



 double x_array[800050][1] ;

    x = 0;
    inFile.open("D:\\a.txt");
    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1); // terminate with error
    }

    while (inFile >> x) {

                         x_array[i][0]=x;
                         i++;

    }

    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

But when I debug the code, I am encountered with this error:

**Unhandled exception at 0x01242327 in textreader.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00E42000).**

When I reduce the size of the input text file (decreasing the input number), the problem is solved... But I need the entire of the input text file...

What should I do? The problem is in the code or I should find a better way?

Comment: Use a vector, not an array.

Comment: When you reduce the size of the input file, the error vanishes. You haven't told us the critical size, nor when the error occurs, but I'll go out on a limb and guess that the trouble comes when you try to put the 800051st number into the array. What do you want to program to do with that number?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than create them with default constructors and then assign values to them. In particular, change `ifstream inFile; ... inFile.open("D:\\a.txt");` to `ifstream inFile("D:\\a.txt");`, change `int i; ... i = 0;` to `int i = 0;`, and change `int j; ... j = 0;` to `int j = 0;`. And you don't need to call `infile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic variables are typically placed on the call stack. The default size of the call stack on most desktop systems is from one to a few megabytes. The size of `double [800050][1]` is over six megabytes (assuming the size double is eight bytes). The result of using such a huge automatic variable results in a *stack overflow*, as you have observed.

Don't use automatic variables for large objects. You can allocate the object dynamically instead. In this case, you can use `std::vector<double>`.

Another issue is that you've hard coded the size of the array, and therefore you risk overflowing the array even if it did fit on the stack. When you use `std::vector`, you can let it grow dynamically instead of hard coding the size.

Comment: Thanks for all reply... My problem is solved with using :    
std::vector<double> x_array (800050) ;

Comment: Thanks, @user2079303 for your reply... I used a large matrix in my code several times... I utilized std::vector and my problem is solved, but this process makes my execution time so slow... In next lines in my code, I should allocate matrix with a size of (2048*2048*50) and in that part, after a few minutes the compiler shows error with this title:
Unhandled exception at at 0x765208B2 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00D1ED0C.

Answer (score 0):

you are (as mentioned in error) doing a stack overflow when allocating:

```
  double x_array[800050][1] ;
```

you should try to allocate it on the heap (directly using new, or indirectly using a std container like std::vector)

Comment: Thanks, @OznOg for your reply... I used a large matrix in my code several times... I utilized std::vector and my problem is solved, but this process makes my execution time so slow... In next lines in my code, I should allocate matrix with a size of (2048*2048*50) and in that part, after a few minutes the compiler shows error with this title:

Comment: Unhandled exception at at 0x765208B2 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00D1ED0C.